# During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred. Python

Tags: python

I have a data frame that has 7 columns, and I wrote a script to create multiple sub data frames based on different values of 'Year.1'

The data looks like this:

```
Month  | Product | Product number | Retailer site code  | Revenue | Dealer ID | Year.1 
January  Beaufort      87110                20021           1500      1222       2018
...
...
...
```

the column Year.1 has a range from 2018-2022, which i covered in my if/else statements

This is the function I wrote, but it's giving an error "During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:" I don't know how to solve this, I've been googling for a long time now but still cannot find a solution to this. Please help.

```
yr18 = pd.DataFrame()
yr19 = pd.DataFrame()
yr20 = pd.DataFrame()
yr21 = pd.DataFrame()
yr22 = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(len(df)+1):
    if df['Year.1'][i] == 2018:
        yr18.append(df[i])

    elif df['Year.1'][i] == 2019:
        yr19.append(df[i])

    elif df['Year.1'][i] == 2020:
        yr20.append(df[i])

    elif df['Year.1'][i] == 2021:
        yr21.append(df[i])

    elif df['Year.1'][i] == 2022:
        yr22.append(df[i])
```

Comment: "During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred" isn't actually an error that is useful for debugging. Please include the Full error traceback in your question, not just a single line

Comment: That said, I'm guessing it's a `KeyError` because your dataframe doesn't have a column `df['0']` which is what `df[i]` is trying to access in the first iteration of your loop. Try boolean indexing instead of looping. See what the output is from `df[df['year.1']==2018]`

Comment: You probably don't need to use a list for this, they're rarely the right choice when working with Pandas. I would recommend reading the Pandas docs.

Comment: @G.Anderson the solution you suggested works fine. Thanks.